# Best and Fastest way to get first value from dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the fastest and best way to get first value from dictionary values? There are multiple techniques, but what is the best (memory and speed) and why?

Examples below. I would be grateful for other techniques as well:

```py
dictis = {
    1: "One"
    , 2: "Two"
    , 3: "Three"
    , 4: "Four"
}

# 1 technique:
#----------------

value = next(iter(dictis.values()))
print(value)

# 2 technique:
#----------------

value = list(dictis.values())[0]
print(value)

# 3 technique:
#----------------

value = [value for value in dictis.values()][0]
print(value)

# 4 technique:
#----------------

value = next(value for value in dictis.values())
print(value)
```

Comment: Your question seems quite broad to me. I believe there is no such thing as "the best way to do something". What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: 1 and 4 are O(1). 2 and 3 are O(N). Don't use 2 and 3.

Comment: Memory-wise 1 and 4 are O(1) and 2 and 3 are O(n) and concerning speed you should just test it, but in general for the time complexity see the comment from @khelwood.

Comment: @khelwood what is O(1) and O(N), and what not to use ? sorry, I didn't understand

Comment: O(N) means that 2 and 3 are slower and use more memory the bigger your dictionary is, so don't use them; use 1 or 4.

Comment: @khelwood Thank you, I think so too. And as I understand they behave similarly as well, Are they ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use the first way! For big dictionaries it's around 2.5 times faster than fourth and much faster than second (10000 times) and third (20000 times) which increases even more when dicionary gets bigger.
Second and third way creates full list and consumes O(n) memory

**Time measurement**

For small dictionaries:

```
size = 10
dictis = {i: str(i) for i in range(size)}
code1 = "value = next(iter(dictis.values()))"
code2 = "value = list(dictis.values())[0]"
code3 = "value = [value for value in dictis.values()][0]"
code4 = "value = next(value for value in dictis.values())"

kw = {"number": 1000000, "globals": globals()}
print("code1: ", timeit.timeit(code1, **kw)) # 0.15313154199999998
print("code2: ", timeit.timeit(code2, **kw)) # 0.25568722099999996
print("code3: ", timeit.timeit(code3, **kw)) # 0.49292356800000003
print("code4: ", timeit.timeit(code4, **kw)) # 0.43500832200000006
```

Let's check for `size = 1_000_000`. Second and third approach last really long (`number = 100`)

```
code1:  1.7961999999982492e-05
code2:  1.607245366
code3:  3.3421025739999997
code4:  6.061599999984679e-05
```

And for `number = 10_000_00`:

```
code1:  1.7192588249999998
code4:  4.457956223
```

Comment: thank you, seems the first 1st behaves much faster than the 4th.

Comment: Your tests include the time needed to build the dictionary — take that part out and make it the set-up which isn't timed.

Comment: @martineau Improved an answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's address some points. First, Python dictionaries are not always ordered by standard, it depends on the version. Implementation-wise they had arbitrary order until Python 3.5, which means the same `list(dictis)` call made at different times could return lists of inconsistent order if changes were made to the dictionary in the intervening time. So don't be doing that in 3.5 or below. Python is actually implement a few different ways, most common is CPython, while another popular one is PyPy. In both of these, dictionaries were implemented in a way that they preserve the order of insertion. CPython is like this since 3.6. Keep that in mind: the order of the dictionary is just the order of insertion of elements, it has nothing to do with the element's properties.

Second, "O(n)" and "O(1)" refers to big-O notation, which is a topic within the subject of asymptotic notation. There are Wikipedia articles on these, but they can be quite technical. I would recommend reading about it from an algorithms textbook, like Cormen's. The gist of is: the number inside the parenthesis stands for a "multiplier" for how many steps you expect your algorithm to take. If you expect to loop through every item on a list of `n` items at least once, your algorithm is "O(n)" (nicknamed "linear time"). If you only expect to look at 1 or 2 or any number of items that is fixed and never gonna change, then you're "O(1)" (nicknamed "constant time"). As khelwood commented on your question, first option is O(1). It is because the `iter` function returns an iterator to the dictionary and the `next` method looks only at one element at a time. I don't know that the actual implementation of the iterator of dictionary in CPython (3.6 to 3.10) is O(1), but theoretically it should be. Techniques 2 and 3 converts the dictionary to a list, which means they have to visit every element, and thus are bound to take more steps. Technique 4 uses generators to achieve an effect similar to technique 1, but it's more complicated to think about and less flexible.

Still, techniques 1 and 4 use the function `values` to obtain a "view" of the dictionary values. I don't know how much work this is under the hood (it could be O(n) for all I know), so I think we should cut off the middle man. **This should be a better solution:**

```
key = next(iter(dictis)) # this doesn't ask to generate a view object
value = dictis[key]      # this is instant look-up
```

I made some testing and this solution is actually on par with technique 1, so it doesn't seem that generating a view of the dictionaries values entails much overhead. Utilizing the same testing as in kosciej16's answer, with `size = 1_000_000`, `number = 10_000` and

```
code5 = '''
key = next(iter(dictis))
value = dictis[key]
'''
```

I got

```
>>> print("code1: ", timeit.timeit(code1, **kw))
code1:  0.002648300000146264
>>> print("code4: ", timeit.timeit(code4, **kw))
code4:  0.0054308000001128676
>>> print("code5: ", timeit.timeit(code5, **kw))
code5:  0.0028101000000333443
```

But may I offer an even better solution, but that would require more work? If you want to keep track of the order the elements are inserted into a collection, you would benefit a lot from using a queue. You can look up details on algorithms textbooks. Basically it's a data structure that keeps track of the order in which things were inserted. You'd probably have to store your data in objects, which is more costly memory-wise.

```
class Objectis():
    def __init__(self, id, data):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data
```

Then make a bunch of these items:

```
item1 = Objectis(1, "One")
item2 = Objectis(2, "Two")
item3 = Objectis(3, "Three")
item4 = Objectis(4, "Four")
```

Add them to a list on whatever order:

```
queue = [] # you should start your queue empty
queue.append(item3)
queue.append(item1)
queue.append(item2)
queue.append(item4)
```

And if you want to know who's first you can do that instantly with `queue[0]`. If you want to know who's last just do `queue[-1]`. If you want to remove the first element you can do `element = queue.pop(0)`. If you want to insert an element in the first position you can do `queue.insert(0, element)`.

Comment: It's nice you wrote that answer, however it doesn't actually touch the main part of question.  Probably RomanG was mostly curious about which way is better it doesn't mean he use it in his program and his application depends heavily on that. + one thing I noticed that is wrong - from python 3.7 it's part of specification that dict is insertion ordered, look here https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

Comment: I gave him exactly what he wanted, the best technique, it just so happened that it was also not one of the four he mentioned, which he also admitted could be the case. The suggestion part of it is just extra bits that shouldn't impact the complete answer that came before. I'll correct my mistake about the insertion order not being specification. I misread my research on the subject.

Comment: I suggest reading the old [`iter(dictview)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) documentation for some more corrections.

Comment: @KellyBundy could you be more specific as to what those corrections would be?

Comment: Arbitrary vs "random", and `list(dictis)` giving different orders when called multiple times.

Comment: *"could return lists of inconsistent order if changes were made to the dictionary in the intervening time."* - Um, yeah, of course you can get something different after you change the dictionary. That's still true for the newest Python version and will *always* be true. Not exactly noteworthy, and doesn't make sense in what you're writing about :-)

Comment: that's not true for the newest version of Python. "Inconsistent" does not mean "not equal". "Inconsistent order" means that if I have `d = {3: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}` (suppose this is the order they were inserted) and `list(d) == [3, 1, 2]`, then if I do `del d[2]` I could get `list(d) == [1, 3]` instead of `list(d) == [3, 1]`.

Comment: If this answer had just started and stopped at `key = next(iter(dictis)); value = dictis[key]`, this would *easily* be the best answer. In fact, that *is* the fastest means of obtaining the first key-value pair from a dictionary. That's non-intuitive and thus incredibly valuable for use cases in which microoptimization actually does matter. Sadly, you just couldn't stop there, huh? Everything before and after that code snippet is either wrong, outdated, or misleading. Kinda sad. Somebody who is not me should just post `key = next(iter(dictis)); value = dictis[key]` as a new answer. `</sigh>`